# Postfix cant find option

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp, email-server

since like 2 Days I have the problem, that I cant send E-Mails because Thunderbird cant connect to my SMTP Service. In Outlook it works and my webmailer works too. So in my logs I got following error:

```
Apr  4 19:44:02 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[18694]: warning: hostname no-reverse-dns-configured.com does not resolve to address WRONGIPV4 Address
Apr  4 20:54:02 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[19275]: warning: hostname mail.mydomain.com does not resolve to address IPV6ADDRESS Of my Server
```

Edit: My IP-Addresses in the main.cf are correct

So I googled it and i found, that I must change the
`smtp_host_lookup` from `dns` to `native`. If I type `postconf -d` there is listed, that `smtp_host_lookup` is actually `dns` so I searched in my main.cf for that option but it isn't there. I tried adding it but then it is still on `dns`. I have searched in all my config files in the postfix directory but nothing similar is there. Do you guys have an idea?

Comment: You need to first check your DNS records.

Comment: They are correct, it worked fine like 6 month. I believe that an update changed this option. I have a record for pointing mail on my ipv6 address

Comment: I try to lookup the smtp_host_lookup option. At this time I dont know, if it's the mail Server because in Outlook Android it works. And in my Webmailer, too. But in thunderbird it wont work althought i use the same ports...